# Facebook notifies others about my new added friend

Tags: facebook

Facebook is showing others my latest new added friends, saying something like "Aiwnas is now friends with X." Is it possible to stop Facebook from doing this? Or make it private for a customized list of my friends?

Answer (score 12):

Facebook loves to change placement and/or behaviour of settings. As of March 2013, @mark4o's answer is still correct, but the way of reaching the settings is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, as of December 21, 2013 it is still the right answer :D

Comment: Thanks, as of January 2015 as well, it is right right answer.. 

Comment: As of January 2020, you also have to click on the sub-filter "added friends" or the control will not show

Answer (score 7):

Click on your name at the top of the page, then **Activity Log**, and set the filter to **Friends**.  Use the gear menu and uncheck the places where you do not want friend activity to appear.

[image: Activity Log Friend Activity menu]

Answer (score 2):

The only way to stop facebook notifying your friends of your friendship changes is to make your friends list private. Go to your **friends list** page. At the top right section of the page click on **Edit** button. There you can choose who can see list of your friends (**only me**, custom, friends, everyone). Whoever can see list of your friends can find out whom you just became friends with.

[image]

So if you need to hide friendship notifications from some of your friends you need to make a custom list.

Comment: Any explanations for a negative vote?!

Comment: Because it's incorrect. Who can see your friends list has no bearing on the update that shows up in the Ticker, which is public by default.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Manoochehr has already correctly said:

Whenever you add a friend, the post would also appear at the top of your timeline, all you have to do, is edit the visibility of at post to "Only Me".